# using ffmpeg and automate it to create video

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I want to create a video from images on the server. I have a css animation on the webpage. I've already written a code that takes screenshots (with dataURL base64) and save them in a folder on my server (using html2canvas/ajax/php). All the images are also created as "image001.png, image002.png etc". Once I have all the files in my folder I would like to use ffmpeg to grab all the images and convert in a video. But I want this step automated and I am not sure how to do it. Using a php code with condition (example if all the files are in the folder) with a shell_exec() ? I am a bit confused on how to mix javascript php ffmpeg.

Thanks

Comment: Have you though of this https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow togeather with just the exec func in php?

Comment: I already read this thanks. Actually I think I'll just check if all the files are on the folder with php and ajax and then execute in php a shell_exec with the command for ffmpeg